# blocking of access of a website after a duration in php

Tags: javascript, php, netbeans

How do I set a fixed duration for a website ? It means that a visitor is unable to access the website before the duration starts and after the duration ended. I am using javascript and php.

Comment: What does an IDE (Netbeans) have to do with this question?

Comment: Or JavaScript for that matter.

Comment: @JonKoops i was just saying the program i am using. didnt mean anything

Comment: Then it is irrelevant to the question. This makes it look like your question is about Netbeans.

Comment: I edited it @jonkoops

Comment: If you want an answer I suggest you delete this question and ask a new one, I don't think anyone will reply after so much time has passed. You should know that your question is poorly formatted, which makes people unwilling or unable to answer your question. I you want to make sure your question is noticed take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask